# Using a mobile plugin with a less well known CMS

Tags: php, mobile, plugins, content-management-system

I am trying to ascertain if I am facing a bug or simply lack of functionality due to smaller, less well known CMS.

I have a site (http://tinyurl.com/c8djrvr)

When activating the mobile plugin on the CMS settings the site structure, when viewed on a mobile device, is certainly optimized for mobile but the styling is lost.

Since my skills are limited to basic HTML and CSS I am less knowledgable with php and CMS structure. Is there a way to know if the site, when being viewed on mobile, it attempting to use a style sheet?

There are numerous CSS sheets within the platform. None of them say "mobile.css" or anything similar.

Is there a way to know if I am facing either a bug or lack of functionality? Which is it?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. The plugin worked when I uploaded the plugin folder with it's default name which was an obscure string of text.

Looking at other sites based upon this platform I noticed that they had to change the plugin name to "mobile" so that the link reference in css would link to the mobile stylesheets.

I changed the name of the plugin folder to "mobile" and now it works - incase anyone else has this issue.